# Bound on $p$-th moment from tail probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

In [Corollary 2 of this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bernoulli/volume-23/issue-1/Concentration-inequalities-and-moment-bounds-for-sample-covariance-operators/10.3150/15-BEJ730.full), the following result is given:

Under some assumptions, there exists a constant $C>0$ such that for all $t \ge 1$, with probability at least $1-e^{-t}$,
$$
\| \hat{\Sigma} - \Sigma\| \le C \|\Sigma\| \left ( \sqrt{\frac{r}{n}} \lor \frac{r}{n} \lor \sqrt{\frac{t}{n}} \lor \frac{t}{n}\right ).
$$
This implies for $p \ge 1$,
$$
E^{1/p} \|\hat{\Sigma} - \Sigma\|^p \lesssim_p \|\Sigma\| 
\left ( \sqrt{\frac{r}{n}} \lor \frac{r}{n}\right ).
$$

The notation $\lesssim_p $ here means that the left hand side is smaller than the right hand side multiplied by a constant that depends only on $p$.

My question is about how to go from the tail bound in the first line to the second. The proof in the paper states that one can do so by integrating the tail probabilities, but I am not really sure how this follows so easily for all $p$.

Comment: For a positive r.v. $X$ and $p>0$,  $$\mathbb E X^p = p\int_0^\infty t^{p-1}\mathbb{P}(X>t)dt.$$

Answer (score 1):

In case any one might find this useful, the approach here is to use the following trick: let $A = C \| \Sigma\| (\sqrt{r/n} \lor r/n) $, then

\begin{align*}
E \|\hat{\Sigma} - \Sigma \|^p 
&= p \int_0^\infty x^{p-1} P(\|\hat{\Sigma} - \Sigma \|>x)dx\\
&= p \int_0^A x^{p-1} P(\|\hat{\Sigma} - \Sigma \|>x)dx + p \int_A^{\infty} x^{p-1} P(\|\hat{\Sigma} - \Sigma \|>x)dx\\
&\le p \int_0^A x^{p-1} dx + p \int_A^{\infty} x^{p-1} P(\|\hat{\Sigma} - \Sigma \|>x)dx\\
&\le A^{p} + p \int_A^{\infty} x^{p-1} P(\|\hat{\Sigma} - \Sigma \|>x)dx,
\end{align*}
using the exponential tail bound, the second integral is bounded above by
$$
p\int_A^{\infty} x^{p-1} P(\|\hat{\Sigma} - \Sigma \|>x)dx \le \int_A^{\infty} x^{p-1} \exp(-\min(\frac{nx^2}{C \|\Sigma\|^2}, \frac{nx}{\|\Sigma\|} )) dx \lesssim_p A^p.
$$
(note here that $r \ge 1$ which is why the last inequality holds).